# Return cursor to an initial position after pasting text from a function

Tags: vimscript, normal-mode, filetype-xml

in my plugin, i am joining XML tags together depending on a mapping a use. It also uses  so i can make XML snippets repetitive.
After inserting the text into a buffer, i would like the cursor to return to the initial position from which I started the 'pasting', but somehow i cannot leave the insert mode.

The function looks like this:

```
function s:DocbkPrintTag(tag)
  "mark the initial position
  execute "normal! mq"
  let result = repeat(s:DocbkRenderTag(a:tag), v:count1)
  if !empty(result)
    call feedkeys('a' . result, 'n')
  endif
  "stop insert mode and resore the cursor position
  execute "normal! `q"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of marking in normal mode, you can use `:mark q`
2. Instead of entering insert mode to paste your data, try using either `put =result` (results on a new line), save the result into a register (`let @a=result`) and paste inline (`normal! "ap`), or match a part of the line to insert (e.g., at the beginning: `substitute/^/\=result`)
3. You only need `:execute` with `:normal` if the command contains special characters or is computed. So the last line can be `` normal! `q ``

All of that said, it is easiest to use `getcurpos` and `setpos` (example at `:help getcurpos()`) for cursor saving and restoration.

Comment: Thank you. The register method works fine, but <CR> does not get translated and instead prints `<listitem>^M<para>^M</para>^M</listitem>`. Any idea how to get this fixed?

Comment: Got it, need to use "\n" instead of "\<CR>"

Comment: Got additional question: if i use register and paste the text, can i then format it as if i put the whole new block into a visual mode and ran '='?

Comment: @TomášBažant `=` reindents, but yes you could

Answer (score 1):

DBK already show you how to fix it, so i explain only why your approach doesn't work here.

From [:h feedkeys()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29) :

> The function does not wait for processing of keys contained in {string}.

To show you that:

```
nnoremap ,t :call <sid>foo()<cr>:echom 2<cr>
function! s:foo()
  echom 1
  call feedkeys(":echom 3\<cr>")
  echom 4
endfunction
```

Execute <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, check message with `:mes`, you should see:

```
1
4
2
3
```

If you use `i` mode:

```
call feedkeys(":echom 3\<cr>", 'i')
```

You will see:

```
1
4
3
2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.